# Provide the correct interpretation of the conﬁdence interval

Tags: statistics

> A sample of $150$ new cell phones produced by Yeskia found that $12$ had cosmetic ﬂaws. A $90\%$ conﬁdence interval for the proportion of all new Yeskia phones with cosmetic ﬂaws is $0.044$ to $0.116$. Which ones of statements below provide the correct interpretation of this conﬁdence interval?
>   Please, give explanation.
>   
> a) There is a $90\%$ chance that the proportion of new phones that have cosmetic ﬂaws is between $0.044$ and $0.116$. 
>   
> b) There is at least a $4.4\%$ chance that a new phone will have a cosmetic ﬂaw. 
>   
> c) A sample of $150$ phones will have no more than $11.6\%$ with cosmetic ﬂaws. 
>   
> d) If you selected a very large number of samples and constructed a conﬁdence interval for each, $90\%$ of these intervals would include the proportion of all new phones with cosmetic ﬂaws. 
>   
> e) none of the above

I would say that the answer is a) based on my poor understanding of definition of CIs.

Comment: You could have a look at some popular threads [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6652/what-precisely-is-a-confidence-interval) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450/why-does-a-95-confidence-interval-ci-not-imply-a-95-chance-of-containing-the?noredirect=1&lq=1) and try to answer yourself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer should be (d).

(d) should be the standard correct choice. The probability that the confidence interval you constructed would include the actual number would be 90%. But strangely enough, this choice doesn't actually invoke any numbers in the question.

(a) can sound correct or wrong depending on interpretation, so not a good choice just to be safe. It's not true that conditioned on these number computed for confidence interval, the actual number lie inside it at probability 90%.

(b) too absolute to be true. There is still the possibility that the actual number is lower than estimated.

(c) same problem as (b)

(e) is out since (d) is quite correct.

Comment: d is not correct. A "very large number" of samples does not guarantee that 90% will contain the true value.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: "very large number" is codeword for the frequentist interpretation of probability.

Comment: Is it? Can you provide a source?

Comment: @broncoAbierto: you can just read any statistic book that has word problem as exercises, or ask a statistic professor. It is not a particularly uncommon knowledge.

Comment: The law of large numbers in no way supports the statement in d), if that's what you mean.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: I'm not even quoting it, I'm telling you that you failed to interpret the statement in a way a statistic book or class expect you to interpret it.

Comment: I'd love to see an example.

Comment: And what is d) supposed to say, according to your "interpretation"? What it really says is wrong, and in mathematics you cannot just expect readers to interpret something else unless you define it unambiguously in advance.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: if you love to see it, you can spend your own effort to get one, or many, other examples by opening a book on statistic and look at word problems (or maybe just ask around). I just don't feel like spending effort searching for an example online for this discussion, the same way I don't want to spend time searching example to question like "how do you know the number of balls in an urn must be an integer?".

Comment: @broncoAbierto: it literally mean exactly that, the probability that an attempt to construct a CI will successfully have the actual parameter within it is 90%.

Comment: Ok, I didn't want to be blunt, but I'll be. That statement is so worded precisely to trick the reader, and you fell for it. It is wrong, but written in a way that it resembles a definition of confidence interval.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: what trick? You choose to interpret it in a wrong way. It's a statement on asymptotic, the same way many statements in stats, and math, use the term "very large". But you chose to interpret it as a specific number with the property of "very large". Based on your answer, you're saying the same thing as me mathematically, but chose to interpret (d) as talking about some specific "very large number" rather than an asymptotic statement.

Comment: But that's not what it says!

Comment: @broncoAbierto: yes, that's exactly what it said. There is nothing for us to discuss here, we already agreed mathematically. The issue is interpretation, and it's not possible for me to convince you that yours isn't the intended interpretation if you haven't studied statistics or being acquainted with statistics exercise. The best I can say is to ask statistic professors, or open up a book on statistics and read the solutions. Stats/probability/combinatoric are filled with codewords like that, otherwise it's impossible to write word problems.

Comment: Codewords? Do you mean definitions?

Comment: Codeword is a better word to call them, because these things are not written with a precise universal mathematical definition, but people who are trained to read it as part of their study still understand it correctly in context. Nobody write down the encyclopedia of precise mathematical definitions of "balls in urns" or "fair dice" or "car travelling on a road" or "very far away" or "very large", because interpreting it precisely require context.

Comment: Just keep this in mind: if you selected a very large number of samples and constructed a conﬁdence interval for each, the proportion of these intervals that would include the proportion of all new phones with cosmetic ﬂaws would not in general be 90%.

Comment: @broncoAbierto: I don't really get the point you're making here since your usage of words is not standard. I already said we agree mathematically.

Answer (score -1):

It's e).

a) Wrong. The true parameter (the proportion of faulty phones) is not random. The obtained CI's are. A correct statement would be "If we make 150 phones tomorrow, there is a 90% chance that the CI we obtain contains the true proportion of faulty phones."

b) Wrong. What if you computed the 95% CI? The lower bound would be even smaller, so this statement is nonsense.

c) Wrong. Same as above.

d) Wrong. If you run experiments indefinitely, you can expect the number of constructed CI's containing the true parameter to approach 90%. However, given any fixed number of experiments —no matter how large—, you cannot predict exactly how many will satisfy this requirement, because that number is random. After a large enough number of experiments, the number will likely be close to 90%, but it could very well be 89% or 90.31415% —or anything, really.